# tcl: string is list not differentiating between integers or lists or strings or ...I

Tags: tcl

I am trying to write a little utility function that will identify the presence of list structures of the following form:

```
{{{{{}}}}} or {{} {} {} {}}, and so on ...
```

My approach will just be to write a function that will recurse to the bottom of every list at a given level and set a flag if something is there.

My problem is that despite reading the documentation, calling the following:

```
proc IsNestedEmpty {i_list} {
    if {[string is list $i_list]} {
        puts "it was a list"
    } else {
        puts "it was not a list"
    }
}

isNestedEmpty 1
isNestedEmpty ""
isNestedEmpty "jifjsfjsk"
isNestedEmpty [list 1 2 3]
```

I get the output:

```
it was a list
it was a list
it was a list
it was a list
```

The version of tcl I have is 8.5
Checking the documentation, the -strict flag won't help (and testing it this is true) - Is there some other way of reliably checking that what I have is a list? (since if I'm iterating over a "list" that is actually integer, say, I'll just get back the integer and end up infinite looping)

**Edit:** Given that string is won't help me ... I have had a think and seem to be having more luck with ...

```
proc IsNestedEmpty {i_list {isEmpty 1}} {
    if {$isEmpty} {
        foreach el $i_list {
            if {$el == $i_list} {
                if {$el != ""} {
                    return 0
                }
            } else {
                set isEmpty [IsNestedEmpty $el $isEmpty]
            }
        }
    }
    return $isEmpty
}
```

Still trying to break it, but

```
puts [IsNestedEmpty {{{{"" ""}} "" "" {{{{}}}} } {} {} {} {{{{} {} {} 4}}}}]
puts [IsNestedEmpty {{{{"" ""}} "" "" {{{{}}}} } {} {} {} {{{{} {} {} }}}}]
```

give me 0 and 1 respectively

Comment: I am not sure if this will help, but you could take a look on the tcllib huddle library

Comment: thanks for that, for I doubt I would be able to use that library where I will eventually be putting this function to use - I'm sort of limited to whatever I can write myself.

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing `string is list` checks is if the given string is a *proper* list. Strings and lists are interchangable in Tcl. The literal `1` is a string that is a list with one element. So the command is working as specified.

Something like this might be helpful, though:

```
proc bar {list d e} {
    switch [llength $list] {
        0 {
            puts "empty leaf found at $d.$e"
        }
        1 {
            set elem [lindex $list 0]
            if {$elem eq $list} {
                puts "item leaf found at $d.$e"
            } else {
                bar $elem [incr d] $e
            }
        }
        default {
            incr d
            foreach elem $list {
                bar $elem $d $e
                incr e
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call it with e.g. `bar {{{} {}}} 0 0`, it will print out a message when it finds a empty leaf (an empty string / list with no elements) or an 'item leaf' (a string / list with one element). The message says which depth (`d`) the leaf was on, and in which element at the depth where it branched off it was (`e`).

Some list patterns might cause endless recursion. That is not a problem, since the interpreter interrupts endless loops.

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm), [switch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/switch.htm)

Comment: Aha, given the environment I'll be using this script on I shall have to see if I can make do with the likes of llength and checking not empty string, and other low level checks then. Thanks

Comment: Nice ... just had a play and it is holding up pretty well